# How can i get billing details in step 6 in checkout page opencart 2

Tags: php, jquery, paypal, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm manually integrating cyber-source payment gateway with open-cart, because i think there is no options in open-cart that i can manage via admin panel. I know there are some extension available in admin panel, but i didn't found any simple and cyber-source payment gateway integration. So I have done payment integration on flat php now i need to configure with open-cart. For this task i need billing address in checkout page last tab. I have searched about this but couldn't found any better and easy solution. Can any one guide me about this.

Thanks

Comment: Is not so easy, you shoud create an MVC for the entire process of the payment extension otherwise if you need just the data at the end of the form, copy the data step by step using just some javascript in **catalog/view/theme/[yourtheme]/template/checkout/[files].tpl** you can append the data you need to an hidden form. Anyway, I've done something like you have to do, but for Consel payment, copying and editing the **cod** MVC structure (Cash on delivery).

Comment: @Vixed Thanks for help.. Where is the cod File and from where i can copy the billing details? Also is this better way which i'm going to do (Manually payment integeration) ?

Comment: No, it's not the best way, as I told you, you should write the entire extension. so you can enable or disable payment module from admin, and also check and update the order status. If you don't need to check the callback from cyber-source, you can copy the **COD** extension which is already present in Opencart, and then, just work on it.

Comment: @Vixed Thanks.. cod (Cash on delivery) are you saying about this ? if so then there is no api fields so i will have to use my self ?

Comment: There are no API fields in COD, if you need it, take a look at **pp-standard** instead. You'll have to work more than in COD, but I'm sure you'll get a good result. I used COD, because after the checkout, the form I post to Consel, doesn't gives me any callback, so before sending it, I put the order in "processing" status, an than I wait the email from Consel.. I know it's a crap, but is not my fault.

Comment: @Vixed Thanks for good guidelines... But can i add fields in COD? I think it should work if i add fields. Also i can save response data in table after order processing. So what do you think it will better for me if follow this way?

Comment: I can't tell you wich way is better, it depends of a lot of stuff:time, budget, experience ;) just remember to copy the COD or PP-Standard extension, rename it and its function instead of editing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97713/discussion-between-vixed-and-ayaz-shah).